# Validating Multiple, Unrelated Conditions

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list-validation

In my list, I have several pairs of fields that need separate validation.  I can do them individually, but I can't find the syntax to string them together.

Here's condition 1:

```
=IF(Outcome="Isolation",AND(NOT(ISBLANK([Isolation Release Date]))),TRUE)
```

Here's condition 2:

```
=IF(LTCF="Y - staff",AND(NOT(ISBLANK([LTCF Name]))),TRUE)
```

How do I combine them and can I have separate error messages?

Comment: If you want to have separate error message then you have to add them to the respective (column) validation in column settings. If you want to combine them and add in list validation settings then you can only show a single error message.

Comment: Ganesh, tell me if I'm wrong, but in Column validation, I cannot check the condition of another column, right?

Comment: Yes, you are right. You cannot reference another column in column validation settings. So if you want the separate error message for both the fields then you need to customize the form using Power Apps(if you are using SharePoint Online modern experience) or custom Javascript(if you are using SharePoint on Premise or classic experience in Online).

Comment: @GaneshSanap For a SharePoint online list in Classic view, what is the recommended solution to be able to link to a javascript file?

Answer (score 0):

Mostly is like Ganesh said, if you want to combine validation for different columns, PowerApps or a custom script will be inevitable.

Here are some articles may be helpful if you decide to use PowerApps:

https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/validation/

http://powerappsguide.com/blog/post/data---how-to-validate-input-data-against-other-fields

For using Java script, you Can Use PreSaveAction function to execute any JavaScript Code in New or Edit Forms for any SharePoint List before Saving the item.

Comment: how do I add javascript to SharePoint Online's OTB New Item form? I have done a lot of on-prem customization using javascript, but not in SharePoint Online.

Comment: @grimatongueworm, for SharePoint Online, you can only add java script in classic experience of the list. That will be pretty similar with what you do in on-prem.

Comment: @Jerry_MSFT when I flip this list into Classic view and go to edit the New Item form, I get like 3 web parts to choose from and there is nothing like the old Content Editor.  For a SharePoint online list in Classic view, what is the recommended solution to be able to link to a javascript file? Thanks!

Comment: @paparush Content editor or Script editor shall both work for you.

Comment: @Jerry_MSFT That's just it, i don't see those available. I suppose I need to get an Admin to enable the Server Publishing Infrastructure features.

Comment: @paparush I guess your tenant did not enable custom script. Have a check on this:https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/allow-or-prevent-custom-script